# WCF Services: netNamedPipeBinding

Tags: wcf, netnamedpipebinding

Tried to configure `NetnamedPipeBinding` in my webservice.

```
<endpoint
                address="net.pipe://localhost:80"
                binding="netNamedPipeBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="netNamedPipeBinding_Service1"
                contract="test.IService1">
          <identity>
            <dns value="localhost"/>
          </identity>
        </endpoint>
```

and binding Configuration

```
<netNamedPipeBinding>
        <binding name="netNamedPipeBinding_Service1"
                 closeTimeout="00:01:00"
                 openTimeout="00:01:00"
                 receiveTimeout="00:10:00"
                 sendTimeout="00:01:00"
                 transactionFlow="false"
                 transferMode="Buffered"
                 transactionProtocol="OleTransactions"
                 hostNameComparisonMode="StrongWildcard"
                 maxBufferPoolSize="524288"
                 maxBufferSize="65536"
                 maxConnections="10"
                 maxReceivedMessageSize="65536">
          <security mode="Transport">
            <transport protectionLevel="EncryptAndSign" />
          </security>
        </binding>
      </netNamedPipeBinding>
```

Deployment in IIS7

Enabled `net.pipe` pipe in site level and virtual directory level and started windows process activation also.

When I deploy in IIS7 Server,
without virtual directory level enabling, it says

```
The protocol 'net.pipe' is not supported.
```

If I enable it in virtual directory level, it says,

```
This page can't be displayed
```

Service name from client side with`WSHttpBinding`

```
<client>
            <endpoint address="http://localhost:60672/Service1.svc/ws" binding="wsHttpBinding"
                bindingConfiguration="WSHttpBinding_IService1" contract="ServiceReference1.IService1"
                name="WSHttpBinding_IService1" />
        </client>
```

Actually I need to try on both `wsHttpBinding` and `netNamedPipeBinding`.
I tried it with `netNamedPipeBinding` Ii faced these issues.  Have I missed any thing?

Any idea to solve this issue?